# Какие классы лучше использовать для чтения и записи файлов?

Tags: java, файлы

Для чтения из файл (строк):

```
DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileDir)));
```

Для записи в файл:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
```

Так какие классы лучше использовать для чтения и записи файлов?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Класс `File` и `BufferedReader`/`Writer`
Вот запись:

```
try {
        String content = str;
        File file = new File(pathToFile);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();

        System.out.println("The information writed:" + content);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вот чтение:

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String s = null;
    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToFile));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("old ID" + sCurrentLine);
            s = sCurrentLine;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: В Java 7 ввели хорошую конструкцию под названием `try-with-resource`, которая как раз позволяет избавиться от такого рода  `finally`-блока.

Answer (score 6):

Низкоуровневые классы для чтения и записи файлов в текстовом виде лучше не использовать.

**Использование [commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/description.html)**

Чтение строк из файла

```
File file = new File("c:/project.properties");
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(file, "UTF-8");
```

Прочитать весь файл в одну строку

```
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
```

Запись строк в файл

```
FileUtils.writeLines(file, "UTF-8", lines);
```

Запись строки в файл

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, "string to write", "UTF-8");
```

**Использование [guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IOExplained)**

Чтение строк из файла

```
List<String> lines = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8);

ImmutableList<String> lines = Files.asCharSource(file, Charsets.UTF_8)
    .readLines();
```

Прочитать весь файл в одну строку

```
String content = Files.toString(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

Запись строк в файл

```
Files.asCharSink(file, Charsets.UTF_8).writeLines(lines);
```

Запись строки в файл

```
Files.write("string to write", file, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

**Использование JDK 7 и выше**

Чтение строк из файла

```
Path path = Paths.get("c:/project.properties");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Прочитать весь файл в одну строку

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Запись строк в файл

```
Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Запись строки в файл

```
String content = "string to write";
Files.write(path, content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

**Работа с текстовым файлом сложной структуры**

Если у Вас в текством файл хранятся данные с разделителями — так называемый CSV формат

[opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

[Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

Например, csv-файл с таблицей 3x3 с элементами разделенными `;`

```
1;2;3
4;5;6
7;8;9
```

Чтение файла с помощью [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

```
 CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
                new FileReader("c:/project.properties"), ';', '"');
 // Read all rows at once
 List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();
```

`FileReader` не позволяет кодировку указывать, поэтому желательно использовать другой потоковый класс с указанием кодировки.

Comment: "Низкоуровневые классы для чтения и записи файлов в текстовом виде лучше не использовать." Не соглашусь. Вполне нормальное решение. Использование вышеприведенных библиотек обоснованно, если они уже есть, например, в проекте. Либо требуется сложный функционал по работе с файлами. В остальных случаях это просто будет overhead.

Comment: @PavelParshin  В качестве контраргумента могу привести в пример ответ Sasha - утечка ресурсов, неправильная работа с исключениями в низкоуровневых методах. В промышенных проектах у Вас обязательно должны быть commons или guava, или и то и другое. Это будет подталкивать команду к использованию однотипных высокоуровневых шаблонов.

Comment: Неправильное использование - это уже другой вопрос. И с использованием этих библиотек можно наворотить чего угодно. Просто нужно использовать те или иные возможности по мере их надобности. Если я пишу небольшое консольное приложение, то тянуть Guava/Apache Commons излишне.

Comment: @PavelParshin Всегда нужно использовать правильные подходы в независимости от размера. Неизвестно, во что может превратить небольшое консольное приложение. По моим неблюдениям никто потом ничего не переписывает. :) _Наворотить чего угодно_ — корректируется ревизией кода.

Comment: @PavelParshin А да, кстати, в ответе Sasha вопрос с кодировками вообще не рассматривается. Это может привести к проблемам в продакшене ;)