# Как найти элемент в JSON массиве? Java

Tags: java

Есть JSON массив:

```
{"Users":[{id: 1, name: "Леонид Мамонтов", id: 2, name: "Глеб Фомин"}]}
```

Этот массив в виде отдельного файла. Как его открыть и осуществить поиск элемента в нем? Например, у меня есть переменная с каким либо именем и мне нужно проверить, есть ли это имя в этом массиве.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java

Comment: ну + всякие чтения файла https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751015/java-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8  |  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486807/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2/486888#486888